# Pausing app when in app switcher menu

Tags: ios, swift

The scoring in my game is time-based and I found a cheat in it where the user can just go into the app switcher menu and earn free points. How do I pause the app when it goes to the app switcher menu just like it pauses itself on the home screen?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should accept an answer if it correctly answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch that event with your app delegate method

```
applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication)
```

Comment: How exactly do we do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is very basic stuff, well beyond the scope of this platform. Please do your homework and read up: [App Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html), but first tick the check mark above ;-)